# Is 'SHOW INDEX' slow/problematic on MySQL with very large tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, indexing

We're using MySQL 5.0.51 on Debian. I've got a large database (over 80 million rows on one table, 30+ million on another, 20 million on another etc, each with an integer primary key, and most tables are fairly wide too), and the server is being worked fairly hard.

The framework we're using (Ruby on Rails) has [made a minor tweak](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3678#issuecomment-2829160), which is causing real problems, and I'm trying to see whether it's something that affects just us, or whether it's intrinsic in the type of query it's doing.

On starting a new Rails process, the framework runs "SHOW INDEX FROM `foo` WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'" for each of the tables (which are InnoDB). On our server, and depending on the load/other queries that's taking between 5 and 15 seconds for the bigger tables. That adds up to a lot of seconds.

Is this expected behaviour, or will it only happen in certain limited circumstances, and are there any solutions (one might be to use "SHOW CREATE TABLE foo" to get the same information).

Comment: Can you try to run `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE table_schema = 'your_db_name' AND table_name = 'your_table_name'`?

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't be slow. I've just tried it on a table that has roughly 40 million rows and it take less than a 0.1 seconds.

[SHOW INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-index.html) should only present information already available in table statistics. 
The only thing I can think of is if there is no statistics on the table and mysql internally calls [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html) but I hope not, that would be quite bad.

Answer (score 0):

We have a same kind of problem with Rails 3.1. The problem is that the SHOW INDEX gets called too many times for ActiveRecord actions if the table behind has no primary keys. You said you have primary keys for your tables, but is there some properties that are something ActiveRecord doesn't understand?

I made a pull request for a fix to our problem having no primary keys, so maybe you'll find the answer from there.

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3812